# How can I get only the width at the maximum?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to calculate the width at the maximum, but when using peak_widths it returns all the peak widths within the signal.

```
    from scipy.signal import chirp, find_peaks, peak_widths
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, 1000)
    y = np.sin(x) + 0.6 * np.sin(2.6 * x)
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
    results_half = peak_widths(y, peaks, rel_height=0.5)
    results_half[0]
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], "x")


    plt.hlines(*results_half[1:], color="C2")
    plt.show()
```

This is the example from *[scipy.signal.peak_widths](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html)*.

I want to get only the width at the maximum.

[image]

I want to use the index of the maximum peak location to find the [FWHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) of the maximum peak. How can I find the corresponding width of the maximum?

```
    i_max_peak = peaks[np.argmax(y[peaks])]
    y_max = y[i_max_peak]
```

I want to get the value of the width for the maximum peak.

Comment: can you exactly define the output you expect to get with regard to the example you provided?

Comment: I want to get the width only for the maximum peak without getting the other ones. I have implemented a way to do it, finding the maximum peak indexes and the cropping the field and getting the fwhm of maximum, but it's not a good solution.

Comment: `results_half[0]` contain all the widths, so is this what you need `results_half[0][np.argmax(y[peaks])]` ?

Comment: yes it contains all the peaks, but I want to get only one width, how can I access it from the list? let's say if I have a lot of peaks and I only want to see for the maximum peak. In the example case it's the peak centered around 400...

Comment: `results_half[0][np.argmax(y[peaks])] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half way there, I think.

You already got the index of the maximum peak with `[np.argmax(y[peaks])]`. What's left is to get the width from `results_half[0]`.

So this, I believe, will give you what you want:

```
max_peak_loc = np.argmax(y[peaks])
widths = results_half[0]
widths[max_peak_loc]
```